# Ubuntu freezes running ffmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, freeze

Every time that I try to perform an expensive (computer resource wise) `ffmpeg` transcoding, including size upscaling, Ubuntu freezes.

Example Command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ac 4 -vf scale=w=1920:h=1408,format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

I have no idea how to debug this issue, and I am not sure if it is a hardware or a software problem.

When I ran the same command on a Intel laptop, it finished without freezing and on the machine in question it does not freeze when performing a transcoding with the same input file but without size upscaling.

Here are my system details:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Mobo: Asus 970 Pro Gaming/Aura
- CPU: Amd FX 8350
- RAM: 16 Gb HyperX (2x8Gb)
- HD: Inter 600p M.2
- Graphics: Nvidia 750 Ti
- `ffmpeg` version 3.3.1-1~16.04.york0

Temperature as provided by `psensor` never goes beyond 60° Celsius, but CPU usage is all the time between 98-100% usage when running the task.